# Windows 10 - is there any way to increase the desktop resolution above monitor capabilities?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, resolution

I have a computer running Windows 10 that is primarily used via a remote desktop. It has a single physical display device connected to it for management tasks, which has a 1920x1080 resolution. (Technically, it's not even a monitor but an IP-KVM.)

When connecting to the system via a remote desktop such as AnyDesk or Teamviewer, I am therefore limited to the 1920x1080 resolution, which is not optimal because the client machine would normally have a better display (typically 3840x2160).

Is there any way to forcibly increase the desktop resolution above 1920x1080 so that I could access it via the remote desktop? I do not care if the IP-KVM stops receiving video input (but I'd like to keep the desktop rendered by the actual GPU).

---

I remember that on much older systems (like Windows XP era) somewhere deep in the advanced tabs of the display configuration dialog there was a "Hide modes that this monitor cannot display" checkbox that you could uncheck and select (presumably) any mode supported by the GPU, but looks like it's unavailable on my system.

Comment: What GPU is it?

Comment: You can probably achieve this through NVIDIA control panel or by purchasing a relatively inexpensive HDMI dummy plug. If the sender is on the same LAN as the receiver you could just go with Microsoft Remote Desktop which will automatically scale to any screen size.